# how do i make an app wait for a notification (txt, alert, ect)

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification, background-process

Im making an app for andriod that reacts to incoming alerts and notifications but not phone calls. the idea is that the user can close out of the app and have it wait in the background for the alert overwriting the alert tone from the phones settings. What would i use when for this? the app is in java.

Comment: look into push notifications http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Android has [Cloud Messaging](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) which is what you want to use.

> Google Cloud Messaging for Android (GCM) is a service that allows you
>   to send data from your server to your users' Android-powered device,
>   and also to receive messages from devices on the same connection. The
>   GCM service handles all aspects of queueing of messages and delivery
>   to the target Android application running on the target device. GCM is
>   completely free no matter how big your messaging needs are, and there
>   are no quotas.